# Why is sitecore running thousands of sql queries in the background?

Tags: exm

When I start up my development site, I can see from SQL server profiler that sitecore (messaginguser) is running about a thousand SQL queries (3400 in 20 sek according to profiler).

The content is mostly like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    ;WITH TopCTE AS (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                [id],
                [headers],
                [body]
        FROM    [dbo].[Sitecore_Transport] M WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
        WHERE   M.[recipient] = @recipient
        AND     M.[visible] < getdate()
        AND     M.[expiration] > getdate()
        ORDER
        BY      [priority] ASC,
                [id] ASC
    )
    DELETE  FROM TopCTE
    OUTPUT  deleted.[id] as [id],
            deleted.[headers] as [headers],
            deleted.[body] as [body]

                        ',N'@recipient nvarchar(200)',@recipient=N'AutomatedMessagesQueue'
```

With the recipent varying between 5 or 6 (SentMessagesQueue,ClearSuppressionListQueue to name a few)

Why is it doing this? And can I turn this behavior of? Or at least make it a more reasonable number of queries.

Comment: Those looks like EXM queries. Do you have EXM enabled? (I have updated tag to be EXM to highlight for the EXM experts)

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: I'm on sitecore 9.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sitecore 9+, Sitecore comes with Rebus.NET Message Bus Service which performs a number of queries to the Messaging database to determine if work needs to occur.

For now, EXM (Email Experience Manager) is the only module using the service bus (which is done through the messaging database), but it stands to reason we could see more use of Rebus in the future as more models make use of an actual service bus.

If you aren't using EXM, you might be able to stop the queries by disabling EXM through the web.config's EXM enabling variable.

```
<add key="exmEnabled:define" value="no" />
```

If you need to use EXM,

One thing that has helped OnPrem installs is turn `Max Degree of Parallelism` up on SQL Server to match the number of cores or virtual cores on the server or local laptop.

[image]

For example, if you have 8 cores, change this value to 8.

Comment: This looks highly likely to be the problem. I will  test turning it of, at least for development and get back to you.

Comment: That seems to have reduced the amount of queries from 1000's to 100's, so thanks :)